# Link and onClick?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events

I am trying to replace contents of a div with a link. The website is set up so that the link sets the div to a new "stream", and I need to modify contents of that stream after.

Essentially, I need my `onClick` even to fire after the href link. How can I achieve this? I am working in Chrome, it appears to fire the `onClick` before following the link.

Comment: How are you loading the div with content? If it is via AJAX, you can use that callback function to modify the contents of said div.

Comment: i have a string of html that i would like to place inside a <div> once the link is clicked (the link does not reload the entire page, but changes the url. the page in question is actually twitter, try going from timeline -> @mentions not the entire page reloads)

Answer (score 1):

OnClick on an `a` element always happens before the link is followed. It is not possible to first navigate to some other page, and then run some javascript from the previous page.

I don't fully understand what you are trying to do, but I think the best way is to do everything in Javascript, and do them in the correct order.

Comment: there is a link (i believe ajax-ed) that updates a <div> once it is clicked. i need to update that <div> further after the update is done by the original site. this is for a chrome extension content script.

Answer (score 0):

did you try innerhtml

http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php

Comment: exactly, i want to use innerhtml but i want to do it after the link